# jenkins kubernetes context not found

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, groovy, google-kubernetes-engine, pipeline

My groovy pipeline has 3 steps (all with shell):

- **stage 1:** authenticate to GKE cluster and update kubeconfig
- **stage 2:** helm install on that cluster (using --context)
- **stage 3:** kubectl wait for condition (using --context)

Now most of the time these jobs run fine with no issues at all.
But a few days ago it gave me this error on stage 3:

`error: context "..." does not exist`

I can't figure out why this failed once, and unfortunately I don't have the full log of that job any more.
It's weird, as the context worked for the helm install stage, so how could it be not found all of a sudden?

what do you think can cause this random issue? How can I avoid it in the future?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is `"..."` context does not exist in your kubeconfig file. You can run `kubectl config view -o jsonpath='{.current-context}'` to check current context and use that context.

As per in [this document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#kubectl-context-and-configuration) Set which Kubernetes cluster kubectl communicates with and modifies configuration information.

Comment: `[Pipeline] sh
[2021-11-15T05:59:04.033Z] + helm --kube-context prod get values website --namespace webapp --output json
[2021-11-15T05:59:08.321Z] + cat /tmp/null.json
[Pipeline] readJSON
[Pipeline] echo
[2021-11-15T05:59:08.351Z]  GETTING CURRENT website VERSION !
[Pipeline] sh
[2021-11-15T05:59:08.628Z] + helm list --kube-context prod -n webapp -o yaml
[2021-11-15T05:59:08.628Z] Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: context "prod" does not exist`

see why its weird?
the command above works fine with the context, the second one cant find it.
the context exist

Comment: What is the output of `kubectl cluster-info`?
Looks like you don't have a default context defined in your kubeconfig file ensure you have defined : `current-context: yourcluster`